# Adding multiple cart attributes to show up on order

Tags: html, shopify, liquid

I'm using cart attributes so that customers in my Shopify store can add additional recipients to a product in their cart.

I have 2 text fields showing up for each product, a Name field and email field. Right now when I have more than one product in my cart, and fill out all the text fields, in the order only the last name and email field are saved to the order, I'm assuming this is because the last value is overwriting the previous values.

Any idea how I can save all the values to the order? I'm guessing I have to make each textfield have a unique name, but I'm not sure how to do this dynamically as each user will be buying a different amount of products so I can't manually set this up.

```
<td class="medium-hide">
  {{ item.product.title }}
  <p class="cart-attribute__field">
    <label for="recipient-first-and-last-name">First and last name</label>
    <input
      id="recipient-first-and-last-name"
      type="text"
      name="attributes[Recipient first and last name]"
      value="{{ cart.attributes["Recipient first and last name"] }}"
    >
  </p>
</td>
<td class="cart-item__totals right small-hide">
  <p class="cart-attribute__field">
    <label for="recipient-email">Recipient email</label>
    <input
      id="recipient-email"
      type="text"
      name="attributes[Recipient email]"
      value="{{ cart.attributes["Recipient email"] }}"
    >
  </p>
</td>
```

#### Cart

[image: image of checkout]

#### Here's how the information looks on the order:

[image]

Comment: use forindex to make it dynamic, so it adds index along with name and doesn't override the previous ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a name dynamic to prevent override, so it can hold multiple values

#### You can change your markup as below to get the desired result

```
<td class="cart-item__totals left small-hide">
  <div class="cart-attribute__field">
    <label for="recipient-first-and-last-name">First and last name</label>
    <input
      id="recipient-first-and-last-name"
      type="text"

      <!-- below code is the key -->
      {%- assign fnlAttr = item.product.title | append: ' F&L Name' -%}
      name="attributes[{{-fnlAttr-}}]"
      value="{{-cart.attributes[fnlAttr]-}}"

    >
  </p>
</td>
<td class="cart-item__totals left small-hide">
  <div class="cart-attribute__field">
    <label for="recipient-email">Recipient email</label>
    <input
      id="recipient-email"
      type="text"

      <!-- below code is the key -->
      {%- assign emailAttr = item.product.title | append: ' Email' -%}
      name="attributes[{{-emailAttr-}}]"
      value="{{-cart.attributes[emailAttr]-}}"

    >
  </p>
</td>
```

#### Expected Result

[image: cart attribute array]

if any doubts please comment